# Partition change advice needed

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, gparted

I need to install Windows 7 Pro as guest OS for few applications I need to run once or twice every month. There is no linux alternative for these (one application reads data from blood glucose meter using USB cable).

I plan to create a new 40 Gb partition for Windows to get the job done.
This is my home computer Intel-NUC with 240 GB SSD and 8 GB memory.
So I need to resize my linux partition.

I am quite noob with linux partitioning.
I only know there is a great danger to turn my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS non-bootable if I make wrong choices when resizing partitions.

Please give suggestions?

current partition scheme

[image]

```
sudo parted -l
[sudo] salasana henkilölle juha: 
Model: ATA Crucial_CT240M50 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 240GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name                  Flags
1      1049kB  538MB  537MB  fat32        EFI System Partition  boot, esp
2      538MB   794MB  256MB  ext2
3      794MB   240GB  239GB                                     lvm

Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: 8514MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End     Size    File system     Flags
1      0,00B  8514MB  8514MB  linux-swap(v1)

Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: 231GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End    Size   File system  Flags
1      0,00B  231GB  231GB  ext4

juha@juha-NUC:~$ df
Tiedostojärjestelmä         1K-lohkot     Käyt   Vapaana Käy%  Liitospiste
udev                          4030812        0   4030812   0% /dev
tmpfs                          810204     9744    800460   2% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root 221669052 45721092 164664712  22% /
tmpfs                         4051004     3916   4047088   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                            5120        4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                         4051004        0   4051004   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                      241965   111754    117719  49% /boot
/dev/sda1                      523248     7088    516160   2% /boot/efi
cgmfs                             100        0       100   0% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs                          810204       72    810132   1% /run/user/1000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct to ask questions about this, so here's a couple of points for you.

Generally, it's somewhat troublesome to install Windows AFTER you've installed Ubuntu. Not impossible though.

Your hard disk was setup as an LVM, and as such, requires some very specific commands to repartition. Not impossible though.

For your case, I'd recommend installing Oracle Virtualbox 5.1. It's a virtualization product that allows you to run another operating system INSIDE of your current operating system. You can **find it in Synaptic**, or probably the *Ubuntu Software Center/Ubuntu Software* too (scratch the latter, as it's only the 32-bit version, **use Synaptic**). You install Virtualbox, then you install Windows to a virtual disk inside of Virtualbox, then you permanently enable a USB connection to your blood glucose meter. All relatively easy, without any chance of messing up your current data.

Comment: Thank you for your points. 
Virtualbox seems to be good choice if the USB connection works inside virtual box.
So is it 32-bit Windows to be installed using 32-bit Virtualbox?
I can install 32-bit or 64-bit Windows, it is my choice.

Comment: Install the 64-bit Virtualbox via Synaptic, and then you can install either 32-bit or 64-bit Windows guest.

Comment: Installed Virtualbox 5.1 64-bit and 64-bit Windows as guest OS. Installation was quite straightforward. 
Only problem was Windows Updating after SP1 clean install, but that is not Ubuntu or Virtualbox to blame. Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: Glad you got it going! Cheers, Al

Answer (score 1):

> I need to install Windows 7 Pro as guest OS…

Do you want to run Windows in a virtual machine? In this case, you don’t need to create any partitions, the guest OS hard drive is a file in the host OS filesystem by default.

I recommend virtualization unless you need high performance (like latest 3D games) in the guest OS. It is much easier to use than rebooting the computer because of a single application. USB devices can be handed over to a virtual machine.

Comment: No gaming just these few applications run now and then. I'll go for Virtualbox.